# Do searches in WordPress count as organic search in Google Analytics?

Tags: google-analytics, wordpress

Do searches in WordPress count as organic search in Google Analytics? In GA admin >search sources, no extra search engines are specified, and only external search engines are listed at GA's list of default search engines. Yet my organic session numbers go up after I do a search and click a result from within WordPress.

GA real-time data displays the sessions I initiate from a WordPress search as direct, but still, I see those organic session numbers rise.

Answer (score 1):

No. Only search engine searches count as organic searches. It counts in internal searches if you do it wordpress and have activated it.

Comment: Including Bing?  Your answer could be misleading.

Comment: Searches on Bing and Yahoo are organic.   Their query data won't show up in the reports pull into GA from Google Search Console, but they do appear as "organic" in the traffic sources.

Answer (score 0):

No only searches in made on Google are counted as organic.

However, you can track searches made on your site and make those keywords more visible on your site.